# How to block execution of code in Angular?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs, observable

I'm in quite a hassle. I'm trying to block my code in JavaScript (yes, I know it's impossible).

I'm using async/await to perform some work, and after that I want to return a value.

This is the code

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';

export const InterceptorSkipHeader = 'X-Skip-Interceptor';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   /* const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);

    if (req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
      const headers = req.headers.delete(InterceptorSkipHeader);
      return next.handle(req.clone({headers}));
    }

    auth.getToken(s => {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + s
        }
      });
    }); ¨*/



    this.fetchUser()
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
      });

    console.log("gets printed first");

    return next.handle(req);
  }

  async fetchUser() {
    try {
      const auth = await this.checkAuth(); // <- async operation
      const user = await this.getUser(auth); // <- async operation
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      return {name: 'Default'};
    }
  }

  checkAuth() { return "hello"; }
  getUser(auth) { return "Kevin"; }
}
```

"This gets printed first" gets printed before "Kevin" gets printed. Ergo: the function returns before the async/await function finishes.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: What do you mean by block, do you want to abort the execution of some running code ?

Comment: I mean I want the execution to wait for the async operation. I want this.fetchUser() to finish before the rest (the console.log and the return next) gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

"gets printed first" string is printed before logging the username, because promise resolution callback is triggered on the next event loop.
From [MDN documentation on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) we can see, that:

> - Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current    run of the JavaScript event loop.
> - Callbacks added with .then even    after the success or failure of the asynchronous operation, will be    called, as above.

I guess what you really want is to use [Angular guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#guards) to check if user is authenticated or not rather than doing that in an interceptor.

Comment: So... I can't achieve what I want to do?

Comment: The answer depends on what you really want to do.
If you want to automatically refresh an authentication token, then you can handle that via interceptor by just calling auth service before making the actual request.
Please, note, that this impacts an application performance, if you have a lot of http requests per page.
If just want to check if user is authenticated or not, then it's better to use Route guard instead.